# How can one use the "other" axioms of a Topology?

Tags: general-topology

In a lot of books on Topology, after stating the usual axioms of topology in terms of open set, some authors include the other axioms of topology in terms of closed sets. I wonder if there is some kind of duality -like in Category Theory- and in case that there exists, how can one exploit this fact?

For example, the duality in Category Theory give us two theorems by a single proof. Does something similar in any sense occurs in topology?

Comment: Sometimes it is just nicer to define a topology via closed sets. The Zariski Topology is probably the most significant example. Any theorem that holds for a top. space defined via open sets, also holds for a top. space defined via closed sets.

Comment: There are theorems you get for free thanks to this duality, just like in category theory. For instance, "any countable intersection of dense open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense" (Baire's category theorem) yields "any countable union of closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ with empty interior has empty interior", and we get that 'for free'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a duality that interior of complement = complement of closure:
    $\mathrm{int}\, A^c = (\mathrm{cl}\, A)^c$.

Thus by proving $\mathrm{int}\, A \cap \mathrm{int}\, B = \mathrm{int} (A\cap B)$,
one gets $\mathrm{cl}\,A \cup \mathrm{cl}\,B = \mathrm{cl} (A\cup B)$.

The former is easy to prove;  the latter is a bothersome proof.